# how to calculate the determinant of matrices whose elements are functions in matlab or mathmatica

Tags: matlab, matrix, wolfram-mathematica

I've got a matrix whose elements are big functions (with integral, logarithm, trigonometric functions and etc). And I want calculate the determinant of that and get a function as output (I have no number just variable I've got).
 So I'm not sure to using matlab or mathmatica and I just hear about them.
 but see function handle in matlab, I guess it can help me... . But I don't know more. 
Thanks. (I know I'm not good in english so I'm so sorry)

Comment: If you have a symbolic problem (which I vaguely suspect from your question), forget MATLAB. It does have a symbolic engine, but it's much better for numerical problems. Mathematica or maple should be much better suited.

Comment: Determinant of a symbolic matrix: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Det.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want a symbolic result I think it will be very convenient to use Mathematica.

Just use the Det[ ] function and input your function matrices. If the result looks messy, try Simplify[ ] or FullSimplify[ ].